# How to stop CountDownTimer in android

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

How to stop this timer , any idea ?

I want to reset timer in every query but it continues. Every new query it adds new timer. How to solve this?

```
 new CountDownTimer(zaman, 1000) {                     //geriye sayma

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
                long hour = (millisUntilFinished / 3600000) % 24;
                long min = (millisUntilFinished / 60000) % 60;
                long sec = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;

                cMeter.setText(f.format(hour) + ":" + f.format(min) + ":" + f.format(sec));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                cMeter.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can assign it to a variable and then call `cancel()` on the variable

```
CountDownTimer yourCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(zaman, 1000) {                    
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    public void onFinish() {}

    }.start();

yourCountDownTimer.cancel();
```

or you can call `cancel()` inside of your counter scope

```
new CountDownTimer(zaman, 1000) {                    
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        cancel();
    }

    public void onFinish() {}

    }.start();
```

Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Thank you so much  yourCountDownTimer.cancel();  works

Comment: yourCountDownTimer.stop()? Should it be .cancel()?

Comment: yes you're right I wrote it when I didn't have access to android studio :D @KenRatanachaiS.

Answer (score 10):

You can call `this.cancel()` or simply `cancel()` inside one of its callback methods

Answer (score 2):

static CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;

```
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.e("seconds remaining : ", "seconds remaining : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("done!", "done!");
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can use this command

```
countDownTimer?.cancel()
```