# Prevent this from happening with the ountdown timer function

Tags: java, android

I have this code in android studio:

The question is that if I give the button back and the main activity takes me, that is going to continue executing.

How do I make it so that once it's behind, it does not run what's in the onfinished?

new CountDownTimer (40000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l)
            {
                crono.setText("00:"+l/1000);
                if(contador==10)
                {

```
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            if(value.equals("tiempo"))
            {
                crono.setText("00:00");
            }
            else
            {
            esperar();
            }

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

CountDownTimer class help us to implement timer with custom time interval and duration. It provide 2 callback `onTick(int millisUntilFinished)` which called after each interval and `onFinish` is called when time duration is completed.

If you want to stop countdown then store instance countdown and  call `countdown.cancel()` in onDestroy or button click(any where by user action)

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203827/how-to-stop-countdowntimer-in-android/40203853)